# Read/Write docker volume from nodejs application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have 2 applications.

1.Backend nodejs application

2.Frontend nodejs application

Both are running in docker containers.

My goal is upload images from backend application and access them from frontend application. As i guess, the only way to share image files between containers is volumes.
So i created a volume "assets" in docker-compose file. But how can i write data to volume folder from backend app and how can i access to volume folder from frontend application.

Expected behaviour

```
// on backend app
fs.writeFileSync("{volume_magic_path}/sample.txt", "Hey there!");

// on frontend app
fs.readFileSync("{volume_magic_path}/sample.txt", 'utf8');
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  express:
    build: ./
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app

volumes:
  assets:
```

So basically, what should i write for "volume_magic_path" to access volume folder?

Comment: Have you considered rearchitecting? Shared volumes won't scale wll - having a dedicated "storage node" (with the possibility to scale to more than one) seems like the better option.

Comment: There will be hundreds of server like this and i cant manage different storage node for each one

Comment: That validates my point! Hundreds of servers with share volumes are an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a XY problem. A front-end app never has to access physical files directly. Front-end code is made to be ran in browsers and they doesn't have file system APIs like that. The interface to access files is HTTP.

What I think you're looking for is to upload files from front-end, and make them available as HTTP resources. I'm order to do that, you'll have to create endpoints for file upload and resource access. I would recommend using express.static() if you're using Express, or whatever equivalent for the HTTP library you're using, for serving your files.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below example , In backend or front end you have write the path inside your container `location_in_the_container`

services:

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - app-volume: location_in_the_container

express:
    build: ./
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - app-volume: location_in_the_container

volumes:
    app-volume:
```

Please replace `location_in_the_container`.

Please check  [Volume configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)